# dictionary-based keyword categorization

Tags: python, r, nlp

I'm pretty new to programming and have been pretty enthralled by its power so far. In this vein, there was a problem I had in which have a dataset in which one of the variable is a commodity name: "apple", "pear", "cauliflower", "clog", "sneaker", etc. I want to try and group the commodities into something a little more high-order: "fruits", "vegetables"," "shoes", etc. My sense from doing some searching is that this would be a dictionary-based chunking problem, but I'm not sure how to implement a solution. I could get lists of vegetables, fruits, and types of shoes pretty easily, but are there existing packages that could help with this kind of a problem specifically? I'm most comfortable with Python and R, so anything that can be used with those languages would be most helpful.

Apologies if this question isn't written in a specific-enough way. I'm new to stackoverflow and am still getting the hang of the thing.

**Clarification**: I'm trying to create a new dataset with these new higher-order labels.

Comment: by "group the commodities", do you mean you want to generate a new dataset with these high-order labels?

Comment: Yup! That's exactly what I'm trying to do. Any ideas? Thanks so much for the help/advice/hints.

Comment: I don't understand. Do you already have the information on whether 'apple' is a 'fruit'? Or are you talking about your algorithm being intelligent enough to 'guess' or 'predict', in which case you will need a learning algorithm and a training set.

Comment: Is dataset your dataset in the form of text, where the words "apple", "pear", etc... are part of sentences? and you need to identify them in order to tag them with their word-category names...

Comment: The dataset is a csv file with the name of the product/commodity as one of the variables. The information on whether 'apple' is a 'fruit' is not something I have right now, so on further though I am looking for a machine learning algorithm. Are there any algorithms in particular that could be useful for something like this?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Here's how I would do it:

```
higher_order_conversion = {
    ('apple', 'pear', 'kiwi'): 'fruit',   #the keys must be tuples, not lists 
    ('X', 'Y', 'Z'): 'letter', # (because tuples are immutable and therefore hashable)
    ('loafers', 'sneakers', 'high heels'): 'shoes'
}

data_set = [[125, 'apple'], #these numbers are id numbers, or whatever extra information you might have packaged with your data
            [126, 'Y'],
            [127, 'loafers'],
            [103, 'kiwi']
            ]

print 'before', data_set

for data in data_set:
    for lower_order_list in higher_order_conversion.keys():
        if data[1] in lower_order_list:
            data[1] = higher_order_conversion[lower_order_list]

print 'after', data_set
```

Output:

```
before [[125, 'apple'], [126, 'Y'], [127, 'loafers'], [103, 'kiwi']]
after [[125, 'fruit'], [126, 'letter'], [127, 'shoes'], [103, 'fruit']]
```

Hopefully this gives you some ideas.

Comment: This is awesome, and is basically what I needed to get the right idea about this. I feel like I can figure it out from here. Thanks so much.